# Entity Framework enfoque code firts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, visual-studio-2015

Quiero usar EF el entorno Code Firts, veo en la web que hay dos maneras una simple que solo se crea los DbSet se ejecuta y se crea la base de datos.

```
public class CompanyContext : DbContext
{
    public CompanyContext() : base("CompanyDatabase") { }

    public DbSet<Collaborator> Collaborators { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
}
```

Pero también he visto que se crea una clase con la terminología al final Map como ManagerMap.

```
public SeccionMap()
    {
        ToTable("Secciones");
        HasKey(c => c.SeccionId);

    }
```

Ambas crean la base de datos, ¿pero creo la segunda opción es la mas adecuada?, se ve que se tiene mas control de lo que uno quiere hacer.

Alguien me puede pasar un tutorial o link de la segunda opción de usar el enfoque code firts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad ambas opciones que mencionas se pueden aplicar segun el grado de ajuste que necesites sobre el mapping

Si defines la clases basadas en las `convenciones` podrias no necesitar ninguna clase `Map`

[Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)

Ahora si hay algun aspecto en la definición del mapping que requiere un ajusta allí es cuendo crees la clase `Map` para definir ese ajuste

[[Entity Framework][Code First] Crear entidad simple](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2013/06/entity-frameworkcode-first-crear.html)

En el artículo lo explico con mas detalle, pero recuerda que el mapping se genera en una clase que herda de `EntityTypeConfiguration`

```
public class EtapaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Etapa>
{
    ToTable("Etapas");
    HasKey(c => c.EtapaId);
    //resto mapping
}

public class CompanyContext : DbContext
{
    public CompanyContext() : base("CompanyDatabase") { }

    public DbSet<Collaborator> Collaborators { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EtapaMap());

         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta el `OnModelCreating` como se define la configuracion

Comment: Leandro, cuando se usa Property(c => c.CategoryName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(15); IsRequired significa que es necesario ingresarle datos a ese campo? y si no fuese asi que es pone en vez de IsRequired?, Otra consulta y si en mi campo de mi clave primaria es un estring de tamaño 6 igual puede ser mi PK?

Comment: claro si es marcado como IsRequired es un campo obligatorio, ya que no permite null. Si quieres que sea opional simplemente define el campo como nulable o si es string no le defines nada

Comment: Pero tambien lo puedo manejar desde la capa logica si el campo es requerido o no?, tambien puedo poner Property(c => c.Email).IsOptional().HasMaxLength(100);

Comment: desde la capa de logica seguramente debas aplciar validaciones, pero cuando persistes quien determina si el campo es requierido o no es el campo como lo declaras en la tabla, si el campo permite nulos en la tabla sera un valor opcional. Si puede poner el IsOptional() pero igual requieres definir el tipo de dato como nullable. El  IsOptional() es valido para campos string